# Is there a way that I can simplify an angular-ui-router resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I already have done this:

```
resolve: {
    required_data: function($q, testService) {
        return $q.all([
            testService.getAdminTestLevel(),
            testService.getAdminTestStatus(),
            testService.getAdminTestType()
        ])
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to code this without the required_data just by connecting the function to the `resolve:` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.  The [angular-ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) says,

> The resolve property is a map object.

This was probably chosen to make resolved data easily accessible on the route.  It works that way in both ngRoute and ui-router.

You could simplify by making what you have in the function be a method of testService, then running `function(testService), { return testService.doAdminChecks(); }` or similar.

Comment: Besides, it needs a name to be injected.